# Angular 10 downgrading a service and using it in an existing angularjs service

Tags: angular, upgrade, hybrid, angular10

We are running a hybrid upgrade from angular js to angular 10.
I have a service that I upgraded to angular.  Then I downgraded it to inject into an existing angular JS service (we have quite a few, so we need to do piecemeal).

I found this:  https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-the-phone-service

However, this deals with injecting into a component, not an angular service.  Long story short, I get the "unknown provider" error.

I need help downgrading services and injecting them into existing angular services.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How we've done it:

1. Create a service in Angular x, decorate it with `@Injectable` (we used `@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })`);
2. Have a specialised AngularJS module (we call it the `downgraded.module`) and have the following code:

```js
import { downgradeInjectable } from "@angular/upgrade/static";

angular
  .module("downgraded.module", [])
  .factory("MyService", downgradeInjectable(MyService));
```

3. Register that module anywhere you want in your AngularJS environment with `downgraded.module` as a dependency

```
angular
  .module('app', ['downgraded.module']);
```

4. Just inject the service like any other.

Comment: I have very similar to this pattern but still ended up with 'Error: Trying to get the Angular injector before bootstrapping the corresponding Angular module.'

Any suggestions please

Comment: Please ask a new question with a MRE of your setup, it will make it a lot easier to answer

Comment: @CrazyMac - Check the following which shows how to use a service bootstrap component to jumpstart Angular loading when the 1st migrated artifacts are services like in your example; it will fix the error you're mentioning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668591/410937